# what are the benefits and when to use template library rather than views in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

For example:

```
$this->load->model('home_module'); //loading a model in controller

$this->data["links"]=$this->home_module->create_links();
$this->data["banner"]=$this->home_module->get_banner();          

$this->page_title='Title';
$this->template
    ->set_layout('general')
    ->enable_parser(FALSE)
    ->title($this->page_title)
    ->build('body', $this->data);
```

My question is how can the same thing be done using views and which one is better in terms of performance!!!

Comment: using template library is better because you can avoid loading views with each request. Using template does the same thing automatically

Answer (score 2):

The template parser is extra overhead over a view file - but what it sacrifices in performance, you may gain in readability:

> Note: CodeIgniter does not require you to use this class since using pure PHP in your view pages lets them run a little faster. However, some developers prefer to use a template engine if they work with designers who they feel would find some confusion working with PHP.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html